# Refresh layer with joined tables from watched files

Tags: qgis, csv, attribute-joins

I have a shapefile joined to data from a CSV file that is being watched by QGIS.

If the CSV file is updated, the attributes in the CSV layer are updated as expected, but the data in the joined attributes of the shapefile is not.

This seems like it should be automatic; why would the join still be pulling old data if the CSV layer is showing the updated data?   Am I missing a setting somewhere to make this update happen?

The only way I've been able to find to have the joined attributes show the update is if I close & reopen QGIS.  (I'm currently working in v3.4)